# UICollectionView cell change self position after scrolling

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

UICollectionViewCell change self position after scrolling collection view. Sorry, I don't have 10 reputation for post images, and I put url to image... First time, I see it:

https://yadi.sk/i/_D9KTVZZfAhsW

After I scrolling back and return to last position scroll and I see it:

https://yadi.sk/i/By1KTz1AfAhto

My code for layout:

```
self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0f;
self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0f;

self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f,
                                     0.0f,
                                     0.0f,
                                     0.0f);
```

Where is my mistake? Or maybe somebody know why it happens?

Comment: are using autolayout it may be the problem.

Comment: constraints using in parent view of collectionview. Not in cells. It may be the problem?

Comment: try it without using autolayout so you find which cause the real problem